# Python: Refresh printed lines above an input

Tags: python, input, stdout

Basically, I'm making a basic messaging application and I need to achieve this:

```
Anton: Hello
Bob: Hi, Anton
Carl: Hi guys!

Write message:
```

Where the messages update every 5 seconds, but the input stays the same underneath the messages.

```
for message in messages:
   print(message) #I need this to refresh every 5 seconds

input("\nWrite message:")
```

Comment: `input` just reads from standard input; you want a library like `ncurses` for this level of control over the terminal screen.

Comment: any examples? this doesn't really help much.